# powershell script to replace a user Identity with a different identity

Tags: sharepoint-server, user, powershell-script

I'm having SharePoint 2016 On-premise environment, now we have a requirement as follows.

we have nearly 100 SharePoint Groups, where we had already have many user's identity added as **DOMAIN\username** ,now we want to add their full Email ID **username@company.com**  to connect the site with Azure AD. In other words, in each group we need to take a list of existing user IDs (**DOMAIN\username**)and add a new Identity( **username@company.com** )for each user in the same group.

Initially we started adding the IDs manually, but its time taking process.

can anyone please suggest a power shell script to complete this activity easily.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `Move-SPUser`?

Comment: @TrevorSeward, thanks for responding,  we want to keep the existing identities also for sometime, and I'm not sure, move-spuser can solve this, can you please explain with a sample code or with an example

Answer (score 0):

You might look into this script:

```
$newID = "%firstname:lower%.%lastname:lower%@example.com" # TODO: modify me

# Get the Microsoft 365 object ID
try
{
    $objectId = [GUID]$Context.TargetObject.Get("adm-O365ObjectId")
}
catch
{
    $Context.LogMessage("The user doesn't have a Microsoft 365 account", "Warning")
    return
}

# Connect to Microsoft 365
$Credential = $Context.GetOffice365Credential()
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential

# Check whether the Microsoft 365 User ID differs from the new ID
$userM365 = Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $objectId
$m365Username = $userM365.UserPrincipalName

if ($m365Username -ieq $newID)
{
    return # No changes needed
}

# Change the Microsoft 365 User ID
Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -ObjectId $objectId -NewUserPrincipalName $newID
$Context.LogMessage("Microsoft 365 User ID has been changed to: $newID", "Information")
```

Reference:

[Change user ID in Microsoft 365](https://www.adaxes.com/script-repository/change-user-id-in-office-365-s297.htm)

Comment: thanks for replying, my site is an On-Premises environment what are changes need to be done in this script.